# play activator debian:get-changes package successfully installs but does not run

Tags: scala, playframework, debian, init.d

I built a basic app, nothing special and `activator debian:gen-changes` gives me a nice debian package which installs fine.

When I run it manually via `/user/share/myapp/bin/myapp` (also soft linked to /usr/bin/myapp), the app starts and the play logs appear on the console and in /var/log/myapp.log per my logback.xml file.

This is all great, except `sudo service myapp start` doesn't do anything. it does not start my app (netstat -an | grep 9000) returns nothing and no logs.

How do I troubleshoot this? I looked at /etc/init.d/myapp file and try to debug but didn't come up with anything. There are no error messages shown and `echo $?` returns 0.

I'm also worried even if I DO fix the issue in init.d, how do put the fix in `activator debian:gen-changes` command. The debian creation is all handled for me. it creates the init.d and /etc/default/myapp files for me.

has anybody got this working? how do I troubleshoot init.d? I tried to copy the

`start-stop-daemon --background --chdir /usr/share/voldemort --chuid "$DAEMON_USER" --make-pidfile --pidfile "$PIDFILE" --startas "$RUN_CMD" --start -- $RUN_OPTS`

...command into my console but I get permission errors.

Comment: Ah Solved! I posted the question so I can answer it. The problem was play also tries to create its own PID file besides the init.d script one. and since my app installs to `/usr/share/myapp` and owned by root (since I did `sudo dpkg -i`) myapp user and group did not have permission to write a pid file there (play defaults to creating the pid file where the execute context is). I solved this by adding `pidfile.path` to my application.conf see (Production Configuration)[https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ProductionConfiguration]

Answer (score 0):

Add a different path for play to write its redundant pid file via application.conf: pidfile.path so it's other than the install location (/usr/share//bin/)

I set mine to `/dev/null` because I don't need a redundant pid.